# Is there any means of restoring Spiritual Damage?

Tags: healing, damage-types, anima-beyond-fantasy

Is there any means through which to heal or negate Sacrifice (or Spiritual Damage)?

In the books it is a concept that is listed in a few places, but it doesn't seem to ever be fully defined as what it is. The following are the ones I know of:

> ### Vital Sacrifice
>
> Characters recover sacrificed
>   Life Points at a rate of 10 per day, independently of the character’s natural
>   Regeneration or any healing spells he might employ.
>
> *Anima - Beyond Fantasy Pg.145*

> ### Spiritual Damage
>
> The Attacks this creature makes against its enemies' bodies weaken their very resolve to continue living.  The damage the creature causes heals at the rate of a Sacrifice at best (i.e., 10 LP per day).
>
> *Those Who Walked Amongst Us Pg. 179*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've spelled out basically all the information I was able to find on the matter, and the rules seem to work exactly as written. The only source I found with more information was *Arcana Exxet*, which is more detailed on how Sacrifice works:

> There are spells and mystical abilities that allow the caster to voluntarily
> sacrifice points of life to gain certain additional effects or otherwise
> enhance their power. These cases, unless specified otherwise, are
> subject to the rule of Sacrifice. This means that Life Points lost in this
> way are not regained in the conventional manner; they ignore natural
> or mystical regeneration and the effects of spells, powers, and healing
> techniques. Sacrificed Life Points recover at a rate of 10 per day (in the
> case of creatures with Damage Resistance, this amount is adjusted by the
> Multiple of Damage Resistance) regardless of other special conditions.
> ***Arcana Exxet* Chapter 10 "Option Rules" pg. 118**

Spiritual Damage is handled just like normal damage: That is to say that you handle attack, block/dodge, armor, damage barriers, and damage reduction all normally. Then, you would write the resulting damage on your sheet with some sort of annotation to make sure you remember that it has special healing rules. (I would be tempted to use the * symbol next to it, from my [days of WoD](http://oakthorne.net/wiki/images/thumb/250px-Health-ex3.jpg))

So when it comes to negating the spiritual damage, you have all of the normal options available to PCs: Intangibility and Damage Reduction from the Nemesis Abilities, Damage Barrier from the Ki Abilities, any number of Shields from Magic and Psychics, and normal everyday Armor are all great choices.

Once you have the damage on you, however, it's much harder to remove than normal damage. No healing effect I've seen overcomes the Sacrifice limitation (and it would have to be very explicit for me to allow that), and Sacrifice is very clear that Sacrificed health heals

> independently of the character’s natural Regeneration or any healing spells he might employ.

One *nice* thing about Sacrificed HP (and also Spiritual Damage) is that because it's completely independent of other healing, a character who has taken mixed damage (both "normal" damage and Spiritual/Sacrificed damage) actually heals faster than a character who has only taken one or the other!

It turns out that there is at least one way to (kind of) heal Sacrificed health: the Judgment Arcana in the Invocation Summoner tree. Judgement says

> When Invoked, Judgement will undo any event that has taken place
> up to a maximum distance of one mile from the invoker. No time change is
> Involved, rather reality itself is transformed. An injured party's wounds could
> be healedn for example, and even the dead can be brought back to life if they
> were killed in the time period transformed. It is not possible select among
> events in the area and time period - everything that happened is undone
> ***Anima: Beyond Fantasy* pg. 186**

Technically this doesn't heal you of the damage, it prevents the damage from ever being dealt to you. *Functionally* this acts like healing to the character, but in general it can be dangerous to alter reality in the *Anima* universe. Because of the nature of *Anima's* reality, there is likely either someone (or something) of great power with a vested interest in reality staying the way it is, or someone *much worse* with a vested interest in changing reality a **lot**. What this means in practice is that the GM is able to make any sort of fallout he would like come from Judgement-ing away a wound. Maybe it didn't happen to you because it happened to an ally instead, or maybe the bad-thing ran away instead of getting slain. Or maybe you didn't sacrifice those LP, and now you lost that fight.

Places I never got a chance to look at, but have doubts they'll help:
*Core Exxet*

Comment: Off the top of my head from having looked at Prometheum recently, there's not anything helpful in there.

Comment: Thanks @Stackstuck, I'll remove that from my addendum

Answer (score 3):

Spiritual/Sacrifice damage is not meant to be healed by magical means, and is meant to be healed only at the speed it states. Judgement is a posible workaround but since time is reversed any effect you would sacrifice to produce would not be of use. And since you need to be a high level summoner to do so, you would not be able to use typical sacrifice means. Exceptions would be artifacts with life activation costs, but again, the effect would reverse. Unless the effect is shot at more than a mile away, and the GM decides to allow it.