# How, exactly, does the Ki Healing "can only repair up to half the damage" rule combine with other sources of healing?

Tags: magic, healing, anima-beyond-fantasy, ki-techniques

The behavior of Ki Healing in combination with other sources of healing does not seem to be well-explained, and I would like to know if there are any rules or rulings about its interactions with other sources of healing and/or alterations to health, such as those listed below.

1. A healing spell that restores points of HP.
2. A healing spell that restores percentages of HP.
3. Other sources of Ki Healing.
4. Natural regeneration (especially high values thereof).  (also consider cases in which a character has taken some damage, regenerated it fully, and then takes more damage later.)
5. Other sources of elevated regeneration.
6. Effects that increase/decrease your MHP.
7. Returning to 0 HP from negative HP through Between Life and Death rules.

Basically, this question is asking "how does 'half the damage' count damage", but there are a lot of things that I think can interact with that.

Answer (score 3):

It's important to keep in mind that Ki Healing cares about **Damage** and not **Missing HP**. That means you have to do some mental (or physical) book keeping to track damage (and sometimes multiple damage types, if you're adding in the complications of Life Sacrifice). You also have to come up with the relationship between Damage and Missing HP. The short version of this is going to be: Track each damage source independently, and track how much and what kind of healing you've applied to each damage source.

Before we get into the details, I'm going to give my standard Anima disclaimer:

> 1.) The rules for this game are vague and contradictory at times. Not every example is guaranteed to have a good answer that is well-covered by the rules, and you may be able to cherry pick rules which result in a contradiction. Specific vs General is only of a small amount of help in many of these cases.
>   2.) I only know the rules in English, so anything could be wrong due to the (many) translation errors.

Now, on to your examples:

1. Imagine that instead of removing HP from a character when that character takes damage, you instead add a new value to your sheet called **Damage**. To check your current HP you simply calculate MHP - Sum(Current **Damage** values). Each time you take a source of **Damage** you add it to your sheet as a new value with an **Original** value (equal to the amount taken) and a **Current** value (starting at the amount taken, reduced by healing), and you add up the **Current** value all sources of **Damage** on your sheet to calculate your current HP.
   When you Heal damage, you reduce the **Current** value of any number of **Damage** instances by a total amount equal to the Heal value. If any instance of Damage reaches a **Current** value of 0, you immediately remove that instance of damage from your sheet. For example: if I have 1 source of damage with both an Original and Current value of 10 and I Heal 10, I can reduce the **Current** value to 0 and remove that **Damage** from my sheet. If I have 2 instances of 10 each and heal the same amount, I can reduce either or both instances in any ratio (10 from one, 0 from another, 5 from each, 8:2, 4:6, etc..). This should pretty clearly work out to the "normal" way that one deals with damage and healing in Anima (and other RPGs). It's more legwork, but you can skip that extra work 90% of the time without a lot of hassle, or just deal with it in your head.
   Now let's add Ki Healing into the equation. In order to track Ki Healing appropriately, we need to add another value to our **Damage** instance. Let's call this value **Ki Healed**. Each time you Heal **Damage** using Ki Healing, you must add an amount to the **Ki Healed** value of the **Damage** instance equal to the amount of damage Healed using Ki Healing. Any amount of Healing provided by Ki Healing which causes the **Ki Healed** stat to exceed .5 * **Original** cannot reduce the **Current** value as it normally would.
2. See (1), just calculate the percentage into a flat amount at cast time and then treat it as a flat heal
3. The limitations on Ki Healing are limits on Ki Healing, not on an individual source performing Ki Healing, thus you track **Ki Healed** an a damage source as a single value for all sources of Ki Healing.
4. See (1), treat each "tick" of regeneration as a single Heal and allocation the healing to damage sources as your please. Damage which is healed is removed, and further damage is treated as a new instance of **Damage**, which gets healing allocated to it independently.
5. As far as I know all Regeneration effects are combined into a single Regeneration value, natural, magical or otherwise. See (4). If there are ways to get two independent sources of Regenerations simply resolve their Heals independently as in (4).
6. This strongly depends on answers to [your other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/148885/what-happens-to-your-current-hp-if-your-mhp-is-altered), so I will defer as I am not an expert on changes to MHP. I will say that at my table MHP increases always increased your current HP at my table (leaving nothing to heal) and MHP decreases took off equivalent current health, but I am not comfortable saying that our table played this "correctly". This does interpretation mesh nicely with (1) without requiring further changes (no new damage instances, no change to **Original**, **Current** or **Ki Healed** values).
7. I would have to consult the Life and Death section of the rules to say for sure (fortunately I interacted sparingly with those rules while playing), but I am inclined to treat this as a normal Heal effect and apply (1).

Comment: Well-thought-out!  I don't know if my campaign would apply this ruling as you've ruled it, but it does make *sense* in a way half this game doesn't ;P

Comment: How *does* Life Sacrifice interact with Ki Healing?  (My default assumption is "Ki Healing doesn't touch Life Sacrifice at all")

Comment: @Stackstuck Re: Life Sacrifice see https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/83593/is-there-any-means-of-restoring-spiritual-damage, Life Sacrifice works like Spiritual Damage as defined in (I believe) Dominus Exxet

Comment: @Stackstuck Re: making sense I've found that Anima works better if you simply try to get a *feel* for the system, and worry less about the exact rules. Always consult the rules if you're not sure, but between the sometimes poor design and the even worse translations you can run into way too many issues if you attempt to strictly apply every rule perfectly every time. The system is based on "wouldn't it be cool if...", and if you keep that in mind and have a good handle on the broad concepts you can usually arrive at a pretty good interpretation that still leaves a lot of fun.