# What happens to your current HP if your MHP is altered?

Tags: magic, hit-points, anima-beyond-fantasy

There is a spell in the Path of Creation that can grant you extra maximum HP.  What happens if that spell is cast upon you

1. If you have all your HP?
2. If you have less than all your HP, but not 0 or negative HP?
3. If you have less than 0 HP?

Additionally, what happens when the spell is *removed*

1. If you have all your HP?
2. If you have less than all your HP, but not less than the MHP you gained?
3. If you have more than 0 HP, but less HP than the MHP you gained?
4. If you have 0 or less HP?

Answer (score 1):

The spell you're referring to, Vitality (p. 129 of the core book), does this:

> **Vitality Level:** 62
>   **Action:** Active
>
> **Cost:** 150
>
> **Effect:** This spell creates a state of supernatural vitality in an
>   individual, increasing his maximum Life Points by +50 while the spell
>   is maintained. The effects of this spell are not cumulative, and only
>   one casting can affect a subject at a time. Beings with Damage
>   Resistance apply this quantity to their Damage Resistance multiple.
>
> **Added Effect:** +5 to maximum Life Points
>
> **Maintenance:** 1 every 10 (15) **Daily**
>
> **Type of Spell:** Effect

Based on how it is written, the assumption is that all it does is increase your maximum, and it does not affect your current HP in any way whatsoever.

In any case where the spell is canceled, your maximum will go down, and the supernaturally acquired (Current) HP will decrease along with it, back to your former maximum.

Comment: Do you have a source for that claim?  (and while you're explaining what the spell does, what in the *expletive deleted* does "Beings with Damage Resistance apply this quantity to their Damage Resistance multiple" mean?)

Comment: I can answer the Damage Resistance Multiple part. Monsters (or *sigh* Chimeras, but please don't) can have Damage Resistance, which means they do not roll a defense roll when they are attacked. In exchange, they get a multiplier to their total HP pool. All that part of the spell means is that the Max HP growth also gets multiplied by that multiple, which makes intuitive sense as those beings trade defensive stats for pure HP.

Comment: Its in the text. What it says is it changes the maximum. Nothing more, nothing less.